# Removing folders from my rails app with rake

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, file-system

I'm trying to remove the `tmp/letter_opener` folder. Everything works fine, just wondering if there's a better way to write it. My next step is to write some tests, to double check that I can only accept those inputs (currently failing)

```
#my_rake_task.rake

namespace :cleanup do

desc 'Deletes the emails inside tmp/letter_opener folder.'
task letter_opener_emails: :environment do

start_time = Time.current
Rails.logger.info "Task starting at #{start_time}."
puts "Task starting at #{start_time}."

print 'About to remove the tmp/letter_opener folder. Press [Nn] to abort. Press [Yy] to continue.'
option = STDIN.gets.strip

case option #[FIXME]: Not deleting the folders
  when /[^Nn]/ then FileUtils.rm_r(Dir.glob('tmp/letter_opener/*'))
    puts 'Directory contents removed'
  when /[^Yy]/ then 'Exiting the task now.' 
    # abort_message
end
end
```

Comment: _Sidenote_: `option` is handled in exactly opposite way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mudasobwa's comment says, your using the `case` statement backwards. And wrongly.

You're checking if input contains letters that are *not* `n` or `N`, and if that's true, you delete stuff. So I could type `foobar`, and it'd delete files. Bad.

Even if I type `exit` or `quit` or whatever else to stop the task, it'll happily delete stuff. Even typing `cancel` would be interpreted as "yes, please delete stuff", since - though it contains an "n" - it contains lots of letters that are not "n".

You also have a (dead) branch for *not* typing `y` or `Y`, though that makes no sense. And you don't have an `else` branch - not that you need one, but it'd make more sense.

You have a fixme you haven't fixed. Your indentation is missing or wrong. Your message ("About to remove the tmp/letter_opener folder.") doesn't match what the code does.

In all, it's not great.

All you need is this:

```
namespace :cleanup do
  desc 'Deletes the emails inside tmp/letter_opener folder.'
  task letter_opener_emails: :environment do 
    puts "Remove tmp/letter_opener? [yn]"
    if STDIN.gets.chomp =~ /^y$/i
      FileUtils.rm_r("tmp/letter_opener")
    else
      puts "Aborting"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks I'm still a newbie  on this and I knew my regexp and the code logic was "passable", but definitely not great. Thanks once again.